# 23andMe API error: 'No grant_type provided.' 'invalid_request' OAuth2

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, axios, 23andme-api

I'm authenticating with the 23andMe API with OAuth 2. I'm able to receive the code after the user grants access. I'm currently trying to send a post request to receive the access token. I continue to receive this error:

```
 data: 
    { error_description: 'No grant_type provided.',
      error: 'invalid_request' } }
```

I am using the axios package to make my post request. There is an error in my request because I got a successful 200 response and access token when I cuRL:

```
 curl https://api.23andme.com/token/
      -d client_id='zzz' \
      -d client_secret='zzz' \
      -d grant_type='authorization_code' \
      -d code=zzz \
      -d "redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/receive_code/"
      -d "scope=basic%20rszzz"
```

I'm able to receive the authorization code from the 23andMe server. I'm then redirected to my application. Here's my GET route:

```
router.get('/receive_code', function(req, res) {

 axios.post('https://api.23andme.com/token/', {

  client_id: zzz,
  client_secret: zzz, 
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: req.query.code,
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/receive_code/',
  scope: "basic%20rs3094315"

  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);

  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
 });
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `form` key you've placed in your payload. It should work like this:

```
axios.post('https://api.23andme.com/token/', {
  client_id: zzz,
  client_secret: zzz, 
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: req.query.code
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/receive_code/',
  scope: "basic%20rs3094315"
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Same error @vincentjp? Have a look at [this repo](http://github.com/joelalejandro/genocog-api), I've implemented some stuff there to connect to 23andme. Be advised, however, that they're having problems with the demo profiles, so maybe some API calls might not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using the simple-oauth2 npm package. 
It can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2#express-and-github-example

```
 // **********23ANDME OAUTH2************
 var oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2')({
  clientID: 'zzz',
  clientSecret: 'zzz',
  site: 'https://api.23andme.com',
  tokenPath: '/token',
  authorizationPath: '/authorize'
 });

 var authorization_uri = oauth2.authCode.authorizeURL({
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/receive_code/',
  scope: 'basic  analyses rs1234567',
  state: 'jenvuece2a'
 });
 // *************************************

// In you view, place "/auth" in your <a> e.g. <a href="/auth">Click Me</a>
router.get('/auth', function (req, res) {

 res.redirect(authorization_uri);

});

router.get('/receive_code', function(req, res) {

 var code = req.query.code;

 if (!code) {
  res.send('Error!!')
 } else {
 console.log('running');

  oauth2.authCode.getToken({
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/receive_code/'
  }, saveToken);

  function saveToken(error, result) {
    if (error) { 
      console.log('Access Token Error', error.message); 
    } else {
      token = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
      console.log(token);
    }

  };

  res.render('/genetic_report', {layout: 'dash'});

 }
});
```